# Grails 5.3.2 with Spring-Web 6.x? Any other solutions to spring-web CVE?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, grails

I have a Grails app that is on Grails 5.3.2 and a couple weeks ago I was blocked from using the recommended spring-web version 5.3 because the 5.3 version is blocked in our Artifactory instance because of CVE-2016-1000027.

I tried to require spring-web 6.0.6 but it's failing almost everywhere.  The CVE states there are no fixes for versions below 6.x.

Is there a way to make this work, or are there other ways around this CVE?

Comment: CVE-2016-1000027. is already fixed for spring 5.3.20 and higher, also it seems the issue is internal to your company repository, so talk to your Manager about it.

If you're not using a public repo like https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web or sonar types, then we have nothing to help you with

Comment: Karim, the link provided shows that 5.3.20 still has CVE-2016-1000027