# Grails5 and CVE-2016-1000027

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, grails

I have a Grails5 application that is getting flagged with CVE-2016-1000027 due to spring-web 5.3.23.

My understanding is that the issue is fixed in spring-web 6.0.0 (they pulled out the offending packages), but there are no plans to do this for 5.3.x.

We are on Java11. Spring 6 requires Java17. What upgrade path do we have to get past this CVE? Even Grails6 is built on Spring 5.3.x and Java11. Note, companies that use our Grails5 server are requiring us to address this CVE.

Also, I tried to comment on this related question, but didn't have enough points, so introducing my own question.
[Grails 5.3.2 with Spring-Web 6.x? Any other solutions to spring-web CVE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75631314/grails-5-3-2-with-spring-web-6-x-any-other-solutions-to-spring-web-cve)